What is this schematic symbol (a dark line and an empty circle) in a small power supply?
This is a power supply to a small audio amplifier in John Lenk's book Handbook of Simplified Solid-State Circuit Design (p. 82).  It appears highlighted below in parallel with the transformer and fuse, and in series with an unlabeled resistor.  It is not described in the accompanying text.  What is it, and what does it do?


This is a neon glow lamp and its ballast resistor.
It is there to indicate to the operator that the circuit is powered on.
As of today, neon indicator lamps are considered vintage (or obsolete, depending on the context).

I was wondering if it might be some kind of an indicator but couldn't find the symbol anywhere.  I suppose an LED would suffice nowadays?

Yes, with some caveats noted here: Is there any reason nowadays to use a neon indicator lamp instead of an LED?

LED will be better placed at the secondary side after the rectifier.

Another alternative would be to use a lighted switch. There are also LED panel lamps made specifically for use with AC line voltage, those would be a direct replacement for the neon lamp, many are even advertised as "neon indicator lamps" despite being LEDs.

Please don't try and tell me that my Nixie tubes are (sob) obsolete!

@JonCuster I'm trying to remember the last time I saw a Nixie tube, and I can't.  Has to be over 40 years ago.

@MarkRansom - they were "retro" 20 years back of so - you can still get clock kits that use them. I remember being fascinated by them as a kid, and using some fairly old test equipment that still used them in the '80s.

@JonCuster nixie tubes got popular enough people (e.g. 1, 2 ) started making them again. Beautiful work but not sure I can justify the $100-$200 they want per tube... maybe once I'm retired :)

@JonCuster  Many Nixies still available eg here on ALiexpress at $NZ23! NOTE VERY POSSIBLY SECOND HAND. || Quite a few here (Google search). ||

Many pretty pictures here
